Support of a probability measure on a finite group.
In a paper I am reading there is the following lemma: let $\mu\in P(G)$ and $f\in C(G)$ be such that $|f(x)| \leq 1$ for each $x \in G$. Suppose that
$$ \int_{x\in G} f(x) d\mu(x) = e^{i\theta}$$
for some real number $\theta$.
Set $A = \{x \in G\text{ | } f(x)=e^{i\theta} \} $. Then $\text{supp}(\mu) \subseteq A$.
Here $G$ is a finite abelian group, $P(G)$ is the set of all the probability measures on $G$, and $C(G)$ is the space of all functions on $G$. The proof is left to the reader and I'm struggling to find one, but it seems I am unable.
Given the setting, it seems very plausible that some Fourier analysis should be used, but I don't know if it is necessary.
Is anybody able to give me at least a hint? Thank you.

EDIT (to make Thomas Andrews' comments clear): the post defined $C(G)$ as the space of all continuous functions, but as Thomas pointed out, this is redudant. So I deleted it.

Are you sure it is finite? All functions of a finite group are continuous in the discrete topology, so you'd need a non-Hausdorf topology. Do you mean an abelian compact topological group? Or are we dealing with a potentially non-Hausdorff topology in $G?$

Actually it should be true for any arbitrary compact Hausdorff group. I wrote finite and abelian because that's the case I'm interested in.

The paper is "Probabilities on a compact group" by Stromberg, lemma 3.3.1.

Okay, the inclusion of the continuity condition made that confusing.

Yes you're right probably, I added it without thinking
